# Using count in Doctrine2

Tags: doctrine-orm

Count row by Doctrine

I have tables like this

```
id | name
---------
1  | john
2  | ken
3  | john
4  | ken
5  | ken
6  | haku
```

when I use this sentence

```
$em->createQuery("SELECT c.id FROM UserBundle:customer c group by c.name")->getResult()
```

I can get the pair of first id for each people.

```
1 | john
2 | ken
6 | haku
```

However ,I would like to get the count how many times each name appears, like below.

```
1 | john | 2
2 | ken  | 3
6 | haku | 1
```

How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

For complicated queries, I'd probably use PDO directly, especially if you don't need to map to an entity.

Here is an example of how to use PDO directly:

```
    $q = "your query here";
    $stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($q);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$em->createQuery("SELECT c.name, COUNT(c.id) as cnt FROM UserBundle:customer c group by c.name")->getResult();
```